# AngularJS: cannot POST to server PHP file (getting 404)

Tags: php, .htaccess, angularjs, http-status-code-404, yeoman

Hi All and thanks for your time!
I am new to AngularJS and currently working on my first form with server side part.
I am running on VirtualBox, used Yeoman to set up.

my HTML has 2 fields: username and password, that are in turn passed to the js file:

```
function authUsers($scope, $http) {
$scope.url = '../api/authUsersService.php'; // The url of our search

// The function that will be executed on button click (ng-click="search()")
$scope.loginAttempt = function() {

    // Create the http post request
    // the data holds the keywords
    // The request is a JSON request.
    alert($scope.session.username);alert($scope.session.password);
    $http.post($scope.url, { "username" : $scope.session.username, "password" : $scope.session.password}).
    success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.status = status;
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.result = data; // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
        alert(data);
    })
    .
    error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = status;
        alert(data);         
        alert(status);
    });
};
}
```

I am getting the 2 alerts (username, password).
This file and the HTML itself is under Angular's APP folder. outside the folder, in the same containing folder: I created 'API' folder. this is the file api/authUsersService.php:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$objData = json_decode($data);

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "select userID from authUsers where username = " . $objData->username . " and password = " . $objData->password);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $row["userID"];
} else {
    echo "";    
}
?>
```

when the HTML form is submitted, i am getting all the alerts from the controller (js file), including the ".error" ones. the data i am getting inside the error: "cannot post to /api/authUsersService.php" and the status is "404".

i couldn't find any solution. tried an .htaccess in the var\www\http folder, didnt help.
please help me successfully get to the PHP server code!
thanks!

Comment: try to access the server url directly (in a browser). 404 most likely means that the server address is incorrect.

Comment: I can't access the URL directly (remember this is a Dev server) I am getting 404 there too. The problem is with the routing I think. I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Using "../" in a URL is a good indicator you're doing something wrong.

You can't go "outside" the root directory of your webserver, so you need to put it inside the "app" directory, so that it's web accessible.